# Regex Matching numbers with floating point

Tags: regex

I have this pattern:

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]
```

It matches numbers but it also matches 3.5.4 as:

1. 3.5
2. .4

How to fix that(this input shouldn't be matched)?
**UPDATE:**
this also should work on input:
1 3.5.4 10

1.2.  is not allowed
.3 is allowed

any char that is not poart of numer is not allowed, like: a1 2.4f 3.  45, 67!

Comment: Do you want to match `1.23`? What about `.3`?

Comment: If your input contains multiple matches, do you want all of them? Could your input contain anything other than dots, digits and spaces?

Comment: Thanks for updating your question with clarifications, what about `1.23` though?

Comment: ronik: Should it match if the input string is `a1.2`? Should I get `1.2` or no match?

Comment: What about `1.2, 3.4`: should it match `1.2` and `3.4` or only `3.4` because of the comma after `1.2`?

Comment: What about `1.`? Is that allowed?

Comment: any char that is not part of number is not allowed

Comment: Yes, I understand that any char that is not part of a number is not allowed, but does a number being surrounded by non-numeric characters prevent that number matching. For example should `Foo (1.2) Bar` give a match on `1.2` or not?

Comment: What about a number surrounded by new-lines? `Foo\n1.2\nBar`... should that match `1.2`? In other wordss space the **only** charcter that is allowed on either side, or is other whitespace also allowed?

Comment: yes, or kind of white spaces allowed; (1.2) is not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Updated answer after comment from poster:

Use lookahead / lookbehind to make sure that the characters before and after are spaces:

Here's a version that closely matches yours, but that won't make partial matches:

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))[0-9]*\.?[0-9](?=\s|$)
```

For both these examples, when run on the string `1 2.3.4 5.6` it matches only `1` and `5.6`.

Comment: is ?:  modifier valid on all platforms?

Comment: Most, yes. What platform are you using? My current solution doesn't use `?:` anyway. And even if it did it's always optional - it just improves performance. So if your platform doesn't support it, just remove it.

Comment: @ronik: I think my answer is nearly what you want, but you need to answer my clarifying questions before I can make something that is exactly what you need. See the comments under your question and either reply to them, or update your question to include the answers.

Comment: @ronik: I've updated my answer again based on your recent clarifications. Sadly the `?:` is back. Remove it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 12):

To match a json number:

```
^[-]?(0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

[image: JSON number]

Use this regex to match `.123`:

```
^[-]?((0|[1-9][0-9]*)(\.[0-9]+)?|\.[0-9]+)([eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?$
```

Comment: This example does not allow for `.5`. This 'number' is JSON-specific.

Comment: Here is an expression that will also allow for leading decimal points: `[+\-]?(?:(?:\d+)(?:\.\d*)?|(?:\.\d+)+)(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?`. Basically it says "either you have a digit then you can optionally add a decimal point and more digits, or you start with a decimal point, in which case you must have at least one digit".

Answer (score 7):

You have to decide if you want to accept numbers without leading zeros (eg .123). If you don't then the regex is easy:

```
^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

If you do then it's a little more complex:

```
^-?(?:[0-9]+|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+)$
```

Both presume that a decimal point must be followed by at least one digit. If you don't accept negative numbers then the leading `-?` is unnecessary.

Comment: @cletus: I recalculated your rep, as requested.  It changed such a tiny amount, I thought I'd better let you know. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not anchored. If you want to match lines that contain only numbers and nothing else use:

```
^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$
```

Comment: He doesn't _seem_ to want to match `1.23`.  (Look at his original regex)

Comment: Maybe the poster doesn't want to match `1.23`? I'll ask him to clarify this point.

Comment: it will work only if input string has one number... what about 1 3.5.4 10

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a regex for this unless you really need to.

Instead, you should use your language's built-in number parsing methods.

I assume from your other questions that you're using Javascript; if so, you should call `parseFloat`.

Comment: I know that I can use (i use c#), but i asked about pure regex

Comment: -1 for assumption that regexps are wrong. Alternative suggestions are one thing, but bland statements such as "You should not use a regexp for this unless you really need to" are inflammatory and do not consider the possible contexts for the question.

Comment: @PP: Before his edit, regexps were wrong for this.  `Unless you really need to` considers the contexts for the question.