# perl - regex for floating point number filter

Tags: regex, perl, floating-point

I need to remove all characters not needed in a floating point number.

For example:
1). 12.23xf00 -> it should be 12.23
2). 15.0s-> it should be 15.0

I tried this:

```
sub retain_num_chars($) {
my $string = shift;
$string =~ (?:^|(?<=\s))[0-9]*\.?[0-9](?=\s|$);
return $string;
}
$string=~ retain_num_chars($string);
```

from [Regex Matching numbers with floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139715/regex-matching-numbers-with-floating-point)

but it returns an error: Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/:^|( <-- HERE

Thank you. I am really new in perl.

Answer (score 0):

this will do your work :

```
(?=[^\d\.])(.*)
```

anything which is a non digit non decimal will be captured

you can replace it

```
?= means a positive lookahead, which means that what follows is a non digit non .
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/zH6jA8

Answer (score 0):

There are several mistakes in your `Perl` code.

First is inside the function. I didn't see you doing any substitution operation over there using regex(`s///`) or whatever. Using the following two lines you can remove unwanted things from the number.

```
## assuming the format is ...dd.ddxxx
$string =~ s/^\s+(?=\d)//;  ## remove space from begin
$string =~ s/(\.\d+).*/$1/; ## removing other things after keeping the dot and digits
```

During the function call you are trying to assign using `=~` operator which usually does regex matching. So change it into `=`.

```
$string = retain_num_chars($string);
```

Comment: Thank you Sabuj, I will try this. Will this work even if format is dd.ddxxddx?

Comment: @apacheix You can try this regex for the second one. `$string =~ s/(\.\d+).*/$1/;`

Comment: Sabuj, I tried your answer but sadly, it does not work on me.. :(
It was not able to fix the following:
9.0088x
40.0088IX
18.0088D

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the Abigail's Regexp::Common

```
use Regexp::Common;
...
... m/$RE{num}{real}/
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$string =~ /(?<!\d)\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?!\d);
```