# Regex for parsing floats

Tags: java, regex

I am looking to make a regex that will parse all floats in a given string. The thing is I need to ignore a special case; floats that are preceded by a /

The regex I currently have works okay, but it doesn't ignore the full float just the number after the /

`(?<!/)[-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`

Below are a few samples:

- 1.25 some text /1.10 some more text:

  - Should pick up the 1.25 not the 1.10
- 1 some different text

  - Should pick up the 1
- 1.25 some text / 1.10 some more text

  - Should pick up the  1.25 not the 1.10
- 1.25 some text .012 some more text

  - Should pick up both the 1.25 and the .012
- -1.25 some text

  - Should pick up the -1.25

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out the source code of `Pattern`. It has a nice regex for floats.

Comment: Did you want to remove everything but the `floats` not preceded by a `/` or did you want to capture `floats` not preceded by a `/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex Matching numbers with floating point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139715/regex-matching-numbers-with-floating-point)

Comment: The difference between this question and the one you linked is the exclusion of floats after a /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Lookbehind* excluding (`/`) is not enough here, it's tricky but you need to exclude (`0-9`, `.`, `-`) along with (`/`) followed by a space in order to match the floats you specified.

```
(?<![0-9/.-]|/ )-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/aC1zP1)

Another way to grab what you want would be to match the context you don't want. After matching the unwanted context, place what you want matched inside a capturing group and access that group for your matches.

```
/\s*\S+|(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nA1zI7)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather good `Regex` question in my opinion. Assuming you want to do a `replace` on any `float` number that **IS NOT** preceded by a `/` the following will work. This is the opposite of what your original `regex` did, but it is probably easier to implement and is easier to read.

**Regex**

```
(?:[a-z]*|\/.*)
```

**[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sZ8jY5)**

**Test Data**

```
1.25 some text /1.10 some more text
1 some different text
1.25 some text .012 some more text
-1.25 some text
/1.25
/you missed one 1.10
```

My `Java` is rusty, but an example usage would be:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(?:[a-z]*|\/.*)", "");
```

Comment: I need grab the full float so I can replace it with %f so even the opposite of this one help :( Thanks for the quick answer